# How to set MutableStateFlow initial value from Flow List

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I have a MutableStateFlow and a Flow variable. How can I set the initial value of *selectedCollection* as the first item of the *collections* Flow list?

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val collectionRepo: CollectionRepositoryInterface
) : ViewModel(){

    var collections = collectionRepo.getCollections().asLiveData()
    val selectedCollection = MutableStateFlow(//** Initial Value **//)
    
}
```

**Repository Interface**

```
interface CollectionRepositoryInterface {
    fun getCollections() : Flow<List<Collection>>
}
```

**Fragment**

```
viewModel.collections.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
    collectionAdapter.submitList(it)
}
```

Comment: You can't, because StateFlow requires an initial value immediately, but the first value of `getCollections()` will be available asynchronously. Either use `emptyList()` as your initial value, or use SharedFlow instead.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try **stateIn**

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.stateIn(
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    started: SharingStarted,
    initialValue: T
): StateFlow<T> (source)
```

Convert flow to a stateFlow

Linked this: [enter link description here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html)